# Как можно сделать, чтобы работали ссылки в доп. полях DLE?

Tags: php, dle

Доброго времени суток! Уже устал, честно, никак не могу понять, почему не работают ссылки в доп. полях DLE.

Смотрите, если стоит в настройках доп. полей "Одна строка" + "Использовать гиперссылки", то если я вставляю вручную вот так:

```
[url=http://moysait.ru/games/|Все фильмы игры онлайн]Игры[/url], [url=http://moysait.ru/films/|Все фильмы фильмы онлайн]Фильмы[/url], [url=http://moysait.ru/torrents/|Все фильмы торренты онлайн]Торренты[/url]
```

При такой схеме работает все отлично, никаких проблем не наблюдается, на сайте все верно отображается.

Но так, очень и очень много времени уходит на заполнение полной новости, так как информации очень много. Я решил попробовать сделать через "Список" в доп. полях. Вставил туда такие же ссылки, но тут проблема.

1. Не важна в принципе, но вот такое отображение при добавлении новости:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

2. А вот уже отображение на сайте:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подскажите пожалуйста, можно ли это как-то поправить? Перепробовал уже полазить и в parser.php, и xfields.php, но, оказалось, что моих знаний в PHP очень малы. Возможно, хотя бы примерно скажет кто, куда копать мне.